# Some App Actions Breaking TImer?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, timer, nsuserdefaults

I have a Timer that i run on my app, it uses a save and reload feature for when the user leaves the view and returns to the view. However if i go to a different tab on my app, the actions needed for that tab seem to break the timer.

Would this be due to thread usage in the app and the coredata of the other tab breaking the timers counting? Here is my timer code

**Update 2: Here is my revised timer code in full...**

```
// MARK: - SETTING UP SETS & TIMERS

    func createStopTimeForRestFromUserTime(userTime: Int) -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let stopDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .second, value: userTime, to: Date())
        return stopDate!
    }

    func createTimer(stopDate: Date) {
        print("CONSTRUCTING A TIMER")
        userDefaults.set(stopDate, forKey: "setStopDate")
        restTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(RestController.updateRestTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func updateRestTimer() {
        let presentTime = Date()
        let stoppedTime = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "setStopDate") as? Date

        if stoppedTime?.compare(presentTime) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
                restRemainingCountdownLabel.text = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: presentTime, to: stoppedTime!) 
            } else {
                self.stopTimer()
                print("THE TIMER IS NOW FINISHED")
            }
        }

    func stopTimer() {
        self.restTimer.invalidate()
    }

    // MARK: - CONFIGURE TIMER ON OPEN / CLOSE

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("VIEWWILLDISAPPEAR WAS CALLED")
        stopTimer()
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ViewDidChangeNotification"), object: NSDate())
    }

    func handleResumedTime(disappTime: NSDate) {
        let disappearedTime = disappTime
        let resumeTime = NSDate()

        if disappearedTime.compare(resumeTime as Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending {
            print("RESUMING THE TIMER")
            self.createTimer(stopDate: disappearedTime as Date)
        } else {
            print("TIMER HAS FINISHED")
            stopTimer()
        }
    }

    func handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let date = notification.object as? NSDate {
            self.handleResumedTime(disappTime: date)
        }
    }
```

**Code in an alternate VC id switch between which is causing breakage:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(RoutineController.handleTimerCallback(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ViewDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ViewDidChangeNotification"), object: NSDate())
}

func handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification) {
    let date = notification.object
    print("Object is \(date)")
}
```

**EDIT: Added the updated handleResumed func and console print out when changing tab and changing back again...**

```
    func handleResumedTime(disappTime: NSDate) {
    let disappearedTime = disappTime as Date
    let resumeTime = NSDate() as Date
    print("ATTEMPTING RESUME")
    print(disappearedTime)
    print(resumeTime)

    if resumeTime.compare(disappearedTime) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending {
        print("RESUMING THE TIMER")
        self.createTimer(stopDate: disappearedTime)
    } else {
        print("TIMER HAS FINISHED")
        stopTimer()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing the timers in milliseconds using `DateFormatter` and passing data between controllers using `Notifications`.

This function is called every time you switch tabs. It invalidates the timer, stops the ticking, and saves the time in milliseconds.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    restTimer.invalidate()

    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:m:ss.SSSS"

    let disappearingDate = Date()
    let disappearingDateInMilliseconds = df.string(from: disappearingDate)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "kViewDidChangeExampleNotification"), object: disappearingDateInMilliseconds)
}



/* add your Notification observers in each view controller */
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(ViewController.handleTimerCallback(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "kViewDidChangeExampleNotification"), object: nil)
}
```

You need to define the function that will handle the notifications in each controller:

```
func handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let dateString = notification.object as? String {
        print("Object is an String: \(notification.object)")

        resumeTimerWithDate(dateString)
    } else {
        print("Object is not of type String: \(notification.object)")
    }
}
```

Quick example comparing Dates in Swift by milliseconds:

```
func resumeTimerWithDate(dateString: String) {
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "y-MM-dd H:m:ss.SSSS"

    let secondDate = Date()
    let secondDateToStr = df.string(from: secondDate)

    if dateString < secondDateToStr {
        print("RESUMING THE TIMER")
        let resumeDate = df.date(from: dateString)
        self.createTimer(resumeDate)
    } else {
        print("TIMER HAS FINISHED")
    }
}
```

Other things to consider: You may want to add some print statements for debugging / sanity check because some functions may be firing before others. For example, rather than posting the notification in `viewWillDisappear`, you can try posting it in `viewDidDisappear`, or using `prepare(for segue:)`.

Comment: Makes sense, though i have removed it and it still freezes upon changing tab! Although thinking about it, the rest timer is meant to invalidate here, so it can reconstruct upon resuming the tab based on the time it captures when it invalidates it

Comment: Hmm, I see.  Have you tried passing the timer object back and forth to each controller using `prepareForSegue`, or `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: Check out Edit #1 in my post.  Gave a quick example on how to pass data between controllers using `NotificationCenter`.

Comment: Hi sorry ive been away for a couple of days. With the final code block, this needs to go into essentially every single VC in my app? or am i just going to pass the 'date' to each vc as a variable in the segue? as if i move it to a different VC then itll loose its scope with self.handleResumedTime? Also do i need to add an input parameter to the handleResumedTime function now to accept that (date) part of the func?

Comment: just to add ive tried to implement the above and get an issue with "handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification)" in the viewwillappear. My logic was that i want to trigger the handleTimerCallback and pass in the notification object, but i cant work out how to do so without error. I have updated the OP with my code

Comment: @jwarris91 Could you post your error when you get a chance?  Also, you don't need `handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification)` call in your viewWillAppear. As long as you add observers to each vc on viewDidLoad, and trigger the notification in viewDidDisappear, you will be able to receive notification events across controllers.  (start by just printing to the console to verify that the callback is being invoked) And yes, you will need this function: `func handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification) {...}` in every view controller you want to update/pass the date variable in.

Comment: thanks i understand now, however how do i pull the NSDate back out of the NSNotification even just to print it?

Comment: @jwarris91- Great.  When you post a notification like this:   `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "someStringName"), object: YOURDATEOBJECT())`, you can retrieve the object by calling notification.object in the callback function.  For example, to print the date object that you passed: place `print(notification.object)` in `func handleTimerCallback(notification: NSNotification)`

Comment: @jwarris91- Updated my answer to include some print statements for debugging the notification objects.

Comment: I have updated my OP with code i believed should work however changing tab still breaks the timer for whatever reason, is it clear from the code? Deleted all the old stuff! Also in your print statements, they wouldnt work as if you put handleTimerCallback in a different bc there is no             self.handleResumedTime(date) to set?

Comment: Its calling 'TIMER HAS FINISHED' when i return to the timer VC so perhaps the handleResumedTime func is broken?

Comment: Yes. You want to change the ComparisonResult to `.orderedAscending`

Comment: You can print the date variables after you define them in the handleResumedTime func to make sure that resumeTime > disappearedTime.

Comment: I have updated the OP as the code isnt working using .orderedAscending, it triggers the else statement printing timer has finished. It seems to print both variables as the same time which indicates the OP code is faulty somewhere?

Comment: Looks like you have to compare dates by milliseconds, because the events happen so quickly.  Updated my answer on how to compare dates in milliseconds.

Comment: that doesnt seem to be the issue, if i change tab for like 20 seconds then go back it still prints identical numbers

Comment: One possibility is that you are not updating the Date in UserDefaults to milliseconds every time the view switches.  On viewDidDisappear, rather than passing just NSDate() as the object, try to format it into milliseconds first, then pass it.

Comment: would it not be a case of dissapearTime being rewritten when i change back to the timer from the other tab? like it seems to write the NSDate when the tab is changed, so if i change from my other tab back to the timer, its writing it again, which would make it the same as the current NSDate?

Comment: @jwarris91 Updated my entire answer to include a more structured example.  Essentially, consider comparing date times in milliseconds, passing the data between controllers using Notifications, and then casting the date string back to a date object and passing it to `createTimer(date:)`.

Comment: This example only shows how to compare dates in milliseconds and pass data between controllers. If you want to save the date/time for later use, you will have to save the string using `UserDefaults`.  When you go back to a view where you need the time string, post the notification to trigger the callback in the view controller's `viewWillAppear` function.  Then you can retrieve the date string from defaults, cast it to a date, and update the timer.